# What String Pass in to Argument of class

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I've seen a lot of chatter on this topic. Though the examples and desired outcomes are always very specific and specialized. Any direction on this is appreciated.
In my Code: I am dynamically generated image and image URL.And add this image control in panel.I want to Put Image url in argument of temp() but i dont understand how can i do this

```
<td align="center" colspan="2" style="height: 200px; ">
     <asp:Panel ID="Panel_pic1" runat="server">
     </asp:Panel> 
</td>
```

Code Behind:

```
var lasToThirteenthUploaded = ds.Tables["title"].Rows[ds.Tables["title"].Rows.Count - 13]["id"].ToString();
int ID13 = Convert.ToInt16(lasToThirteenthUploaded);//row.Field<int>("video_id");
Image img13 = new Image();
img13.ID = "image" + ID13;
string title13 = ds.Tables["title"].Rows[ds.Tables["title"].Rows.Count - 13]["title"].ToString();//row.Field<string>("title");
img13.ImageUrl = ds.Tables["title"].Rows[ds.Tables["title"].Rows.Count - 13]["path"].ToString();// ("image_path");
Panel_pic13.Controls.Add(img13);

protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["Name"] == null)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        temp();
    }
}
protected void temp()
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass value from here

```
else
{
temp(img13.ImageUrl);
}
```

and grab it in

```
void temp(string imageurl)
{
}
```

you could use protected void temp(string imageurl) also